# My codeigniter form sends textarea using post, and does not send input type text

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, post, input

All.

My Codeigniter has one input type="text" and one textarea. Already on sending I can see (Chrome network sources), that $_POST array does not include input type="text" field, but includes textarea! I even tried to change input to textarea and it worked...

```
<form action="news_save" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 

  <label class="control-label span3" for="subj">Subject</label>
  <input type="text" id="subj" name-"subj" class="row-fluid">

  <label class="control-label span3" for="body">Body</label>
  <textarea rows="3" name="body" class="row-fluid" id="body"></textarea>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Any suggestions, what can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  problem in input text near name attribute, instead of - it should be =

```
<input type="text" id="subj" name-"subj" class="row-fluid">
```

change it to this

```
<input type="text" id="subj" name="subj" class="row-fluid">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array= array(namedb' => $this->input->post('body'));
```

> and after insert to db.

```
$this->ModelFile->MetodModel($array);
```